# Trim output of a Keras feed forward network

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm using a simple feed forward network in Keras for a regression problem. The setup of the network is quite simple: 3 hidden layers with tanh activation, output layer has a single node with linear activation.

However, I noticed that the output has some fairly extreme values like the below:

[image: Output of network]

I'm a bit concerned that the extreme values will dominate the loss function (MSE) so I'd like to trim it. Is there a way to do this in Keras?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099233/keras-regression-clip-values) similar to what you are looking to do?

Comment: Yes! Now I need to figure out how to effectively implement winsorization in Keras (so I'm not clipping by some hard values). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean regularization ( L1, L2, ... ) : https://keras.io/regularizers/ ( i.e. in the `Dense` layer )

also see https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda

Comment: I think Lambda or keras.backend.clip in the above are closer to what I'm after. Thanks!